# Zoom in/out and rotate div with smooth transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my first post!
I have been doing some experiments, trying to recreate something i saw.
Here is what i am trying to achieve:

[Scroll at the end of this page and take a look at animated buttons for twitter, youtube, facebook](http://www.cropp.com/pl/en/)

Now take a look at my code:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="letter">A</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.container{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:purple;
overflow:hidden;
}

.letter{
text-align:center;
font-size:50px;
line-height:170px;
color:white;
}

.letter:hover{
cursor:pointer;
}

.letter.zoom{
transform:rotate(15deg) scale(3);
transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
   $('.container').on('click', function(){
      $('.letter').toggleClass('zoom');
   });
});
```

Now, if you run the code, you will see letter A, and on click it will zoom in and slightly rotate. Here are my issues:

1.how to do this on hover, using css3 or jquery or javascript?(not onmouseover/onmouseout)

2.how to make the rendering smoother?(the letter zooms in in poor resolution and than renders to full quality)

3.it has animated transition on zoom in. When it zooms out there is no animation or transition. How to do the animation on zoom out, on hover out?

I have tried to do separately just zoom in and just rotate, and it works, but if i want to do both in the same time, CSS3 is overriding one with another, and using this function is not giving me the result i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with just CSS:

Transition:

```
.letter {
    transition: ease .25s; // when set on selector itself, will apply to all pseudo-classes such as: :hover, :active, :focus, etc.
    -webkit-transition: ease .25s;
}
```

Zoom:

```
.letter:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5); // Alternatively, you can use percentages
    -wekbit-transform: scale(1.5); // Chrome / Safari
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5); // Firefox
}
```

Rotate:

```
.letter:hover {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    -wekbit-transform: rotate(15deg); // Chrome / Safari
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg); // Firefox
}
```

Comment: Thanks transition part is working great, just what i wanted! Now, the hover part is giving me some strange reaction because the div is jumping on it, but it may be because of some of the settings in CSS. I will try to discover why. While we are on this topic, how can i implement the "hover" effect in my function? I tried .on('hover') but it is not working. Any suggestions? Just to edit, this little function is handy becuse it toggles the classes, turning them on and off. I would like to implement hover effect instead of click.

Comment: You had it close. You can either do $(".class").on("hover", function {  }); or $(".class").hover(function() {  });

Comment: Perfect! Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Don't forget to put `:focus` styles everywhere you put `:hover` so you can support those who use a keyboard to navigate the page. Same deal if you use script instead of CSS.

Comment: @aardrian definitely. I didn't want it to seem confusing by including :focus or :active, but in the long run you will definitely want to include those.